# Reading very large line from stdin using sys.stdin.readline in Python

Tags: python, readline

While trying to write a program to certain specifications, which include requiring the program to read information from `stdin` and print output to `stdout`, I have run into an unexpected problem. The problem is that `sys.stdin.readline()` doesn't finish reading the line provided to it on `stdin`.

## Minimal Example

```
#!/bin/python

from sys import stdin
myline = stdin.readline().split()
```

The line to be read is found at http://pastebin.com/k3DsD5f6

On my MacBook Pro running 10.8.5 and Python 2.7, the program hangs indefinitely at the line involving the `readline()` command.

The exact terminal output I get (assuming I name this snippet of code `so_error.py`) is as follows.

```
python so_error.py
30887 92778 36916 47794 38336 85387 60493 16650 41422 2363 90028 68691 20060 97764 13927 80541 83427 89173 55737 5212 95369 2568 56430 65783 21531 22863 65124 74068 3136 13930 79803 34023 23059 33070 98168 61394 18457 75012 78043 76230 77374 84422 44920 13785 98538 75199 94325 98316 64371 66414 3527 76092 68981 59957 41874 6863 99171 6997 97282 2306 20926 77085 36328 60337 26506 50847 21730 61314 25858 16125 53896 19583 546 98815 33368 15435 90365 44044 13751 71088 26809 17277 47179 95789 93585 5404 2652 92755 12400 99933 95061 49677 93369 47740 10013 36227 98587 48095 97540 40796 80571 51435 60379 97468 66602 10098 12903 73318 70493 26653 60757 97302 60281 24287 9442 53866 29690 28445 46620 58441 44730 58032 8118 38098 5772 34482 90676 20710 98928 4568 77857 79498 72354 54587 76966 55307 64684 6220 28625 51529 32872 5733 48830 9504 30020 58271 63369 59709 86716 26341 18150 47797 724 42619 2246 22847 93452 92922 43556 92380 97489 37765 88229 69842 92351 65194 41501 57035 87765 70125 24915 36988 75857 73744 46
```

It always stops at this exact point, so this is likely some kind of an overflow error. The code works just fine with a short line.

Comment: how are you reading it?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't understand your question? One can save that snippet of code in a file, let's call it `so_error.py` and call it from the command line. Once the prompt comes up, paste the line.

Comment: I mean where is the line coming from? Why are you pasting one lone line?

Comment: :-) Just working to a specification. I have to write a procedure that takes inputs from `stdin` and prints output to `stdout`.

Comment: I don't think this is an overflow error because Python can store strings much larger than that...If you actually do get an overflow error, I recommend using buffered input with a set finite number of bytes.

Comment: Does the error also persist on your machine?

Comment: so `python your_file.py  < longline.txt` hangs?

Comment: No. `python so_error.py < longline.txt` works.

Comment: Try reading until end of file. Example, try: myline = stdin.readlines().split() except EOFerror

Comment: It is an os issue you are seeing not a python error, your long line is not really long at all. Can you explain exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: `try: stdin.readline().split() except EOFerror: pass` also hangs.

Comment: He meant readlines with a 's'

Comment: @CCG. that is not how I would read from stdin

Comment: Try `myline = stdin.readlines()[0].split()`

Comment: @jakekimds, there is nothing in what the OP has shown that would cause any issue, also readlines().split() would cause an error not make the script hang

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I agree with you, it is stupid to demand that inputs be provided in this way. But given that this is how they're being asked, is there any way around? Or should I just give up because this is some kind of strange OS error?

Comment: I cannot replicate using linux, if I paste the lines I get an error from bash. If I read using redirection it works fine, I cannot see how it would cause the script to hang, if you hit return again while seemingly hanging does anything happen?

Comment: Hitting return doesn't do anything. However `ctrl+c` still works and throws the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.

Comment: @CCG, is the string you pass a single string with no spaces or exactly as in your pastebin file?

Comment: 1 string with 1 trailing newline character.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73980/discussion-between-ccg-and-padraic-cunningham).

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this using unbuffered stdin (`python -u`) on Windows -- not on linux however.

Comment: @CCG, if you simply paste that string into bash without running the script what happens?

Comment: The entire string prints, followed by an error `-bash: 30887: command not found`

Comment: @CCG, if you join it into one long single string, `"".join( open("longline.txt").read())` and paste it into bash, that is the only way I can replicate your error. pasting the lines as you have posted in pastebin gives me an error like yours above

Comment: That should be `"".join( open("longline.txt").read().split())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not `readline()` at all but the way you execute the script. Since you're reading from stdin you need to supply stdin with the data to be read. If you don't, the program will hang indefinitely (same as if you ran `cat` with no arguments).

I took your example code and input file and was able to successfully run it like this:

```
$ python so_error.py <longline.txt
```

It exits successfully and rather quickly. I also added `print myline` at the end of your script to verify that it was indeed parsing everything correctly.